# The Password textbox is looks wrong

Tags: html, bootstrap-form-helper

I'm creating the form in a medal for user registration but the password area has no frame. The page looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/elxlzl).

And the code:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="_password">Şifre:</label>
    <p style="font-size:13px;">*Şifreniz en az 1 büyük/küçük harf, sayı ve özel karakterler içermelidir!</p>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="_password" placeholder="Şifrenizi dikkatlice giriniz" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="_repassword" placeholder="Şifrenizi tekrar giriniz" required> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have some CSS rules with the selector `input[type=text]`. If this is the case, add `input[type=password]` as well to those.

Comment: How can i do that, im fresh with html and css

Comment: Can you provide some of the existing CSS for the page?

Comment: At line 11, note "border: 3px solid #fff". That means you'll use a 3px side white border which is why it looks like the field has no border. It's probably being overwritten for text fields by bootstrap's css, so try changing it to "border: 1px solid #444" which will give the field a grayish border that looks similar to the other borders.

Comment: Hmmm... You could also try right clicking the field and choosing inspect element. Then, you'd see any CSS rules relating to the password field. There's still probably some CSS rule somewhere hiding the border or making it white. I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: You may find CSS tutorials online helpful in this case.

Comment: Okay, i will watch some tutorials. Thank you for your help :)